# How can I assign a unique id to each datapoint in a queue?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using queues to load data in tensorflow.  My data is stored in TFRecords.  The problem is that I want a unique id associated with each data point, but I don't know how to do this.  (The UID will be used to either filter portions of the dataset, or add noise to the dataset; the UID is need to ensure that in each epoch, the same data points get filtered or the same noise gets added.)

I read the datapoints using this code:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(datapaths)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    })
image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32
```

I then use `image` and `label` variables like normal.  I want to also have a `uid` variable that is unique for each data point.  Ideally, this would be an integer between 0 and the size of the dataset, and `uid` would just be the index of the current data point.  How can I create this `uid` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  The idea is to create a new queue that stores the uids.  It's important that none of the queues shuffle the data so that all the information remains synchronized.

In case anyone else needs something like this in the future, here's the code:

```
numdp=training_size 
uidqueue = tf.FIFOQueue(1000,tf.int32) 
uidcounter = tf.Variable(0,name='uidcounter') 
enqueue_op = uidqueue.enqueue(uidcounter.assign((uidcounter+1)%numdp)) 
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(uidqueue,[enqueue_op]) 
queue_runner.add_queue_runner(qr) 
uid = uidqueue.dequeue()
```